# How do I print messages to the screen in my Java GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm creating a GUI ATM machine. How can I print messages to the screen? I have buttons 0-9 as well as an enter and cancel set up, for the user to press.

Comment: Start with the tutorials. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html

Answer (score 2):

You should put a JTextField or a JLabel into your program. These two components display text that the user can read. I suggest using a JTextField, mostly because I love using text boxes. Here's an example of how to use the text:

http://leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI/components/30textfield/11textfield.html

Basically you should do

```
JTextField myOutput = new JTextField(16);
```

Where myOutput is what you choose the JTextField's variable to be and 16 is the length of the JTextField in the GUI. To display a message:

```
myOutput.setText("some text");
```

You can also initialize the value of the JTextField while declaring the text field at the same time

```
JTextField myOutput = new JTextField("someInitialValue", 20);
```

The code speaks for itself

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You would want to assign this value to some GUI component, such as a `JTextField` or `JLabel`, by using the `setText(String text)` method on said component.